# SDL FPS input delay

Tags: graphics, time, input, sdl

I am using SDL in my playground project and i am a bit worried about my PC performance - it is too high or I am just wandering.

The thing is, when I change the coordinates of some sprite when the key on keyboard is down, for example, by `2 px` the sprite moves too fast. And the same is valid for `1 px` velocity.

Usually (in SFML) I do the next velocity changes: `1.f / App->GetTimeSinceLastFrame()` and it works just perfectly! But now I wanna use SDL. And I can not choose delays because they will not be identical on different PCs (and that is a very ugly way for sure) or float-value conversions because of the next reason.

Doing `lastTicks = SDL_GetTicks()` and then using `1.f / (float) SDL_GetTicks() - lastTicks()` does the bad job - that difference is always **zero**. So either I am mistaken or the time between two frames is so small that it is rounded to `0`.

Can anyone give me an advice what should I do?

**NOTE:** *change SDL to xxx* is not a good advice ;)

Comment: `SDL_GetTicks` is millisecond only resolution, so for high fps the difference will be *mostly* zero (so rounded in a sense but should accumulate and be one once in a while). make sure you only use one call, so `cur=get();diff=cur-last;last=cur;`. a higher resolution timing method might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to do more than 60 fps (monitor refresh rate). You are only wasting CPU time. Call `SDL_Delay` if your game is running too fast.

```
    int delay=1000/maxFPS-SDL_GetTicks()+lastTicks;

    if(delay>0)
        SDL_Delay(delay);
```

Comment: To add to this answer: be careful to check input/events after the delay in the main loop. v-sync behaves differently but I'm similarly frustrated at 10-30ms mouse movement delays in certain 3d apps, especially games.